# cannot delete row from db in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have 2 pages sell.php and sell_form.php . When a user selects a stock symbol from the drop-down menu in sell_form.php i have a query in sell.php that is supposed to delete that stock symbol from the database, but what i am getting right now is just a blank page when i click on Sell button. I am not sure i fully understand how the value from the drop-down menu is passed to the sell.php form. This is the code i have so far

this is my sell.php file

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{



    // delete the stock from their portfolio 
query("DELETE FROM shares WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", $_SESSION["id"],$_POST["symbol"]);  

redirect("/");
}
else
{

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    //create array to store the shares
    $shares = [];

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        //lookup stock info
        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);
        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = [
                "name" => $stock["name"],
                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "shares" => $row["shares"],
                "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]
            ];

        }
    }

// render portfolio
render("sell_form.php", ["shares" => $shares, "title" => "Sell"] );
}
```

this is my sell_form.php

```
<form action="sell.php" method="post">
<fieldset>     
    <div class="control-group">

        <select name="symbol">
        <option value="blank"></option>

        <?php foreach ($shares as $symbol):?>
        <option value="symbol"><?= $symbol["symbol"]?></option>
         <? endforeach ?>
        </select>     

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sell all shares</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: is the portfolio is deleted from table when the blank page is showing?

Comment: for some reason symbol is not being passed to the query. if i remove symbol then the whole portfolio gets deleted according to the user id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We think in sell_form.php,

```
<option value="symbol"><?= $symbol["symbol"]?></option>
```

should be changed as

```
<option value="<?= $symbol["symbol"]?>"><?= $symbol["symbol"]?></option>
```

Other-wise in sell.php

the delete statement is interpreting as -

```
DELETE FROM shares WHERE id = <<Spefied User Id>> AND symbol = 'symbol';
```

Thnaks